# Use Chrome Extension to Modify Google Search Result Page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I wanna make a Chrome extension to modify Google search result page. I know I can use content script to do this because it has the ability to do this. But unfortunately it fails. I wrote the code

```
$('h3.r').append('<b>a</b>')
```

or something else related to DOM operations they all failed. But if I just wrote

```
alert('aa')
```

or

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor='green'
```

, it works. Why?
By the way, I want to have a debug but when I open the development tools I can not find my extension content script. I can see other extensions' content scripts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you add jQuery to your content_scripts in manifest?

If you use jQuery, you must write `manifest.json` like this:

```
 "content_scripts":[
        {
            "matches":["http://www.google.com/*"],
            "js":["jquery-1.9.1.min.js", "contentscripts.js"]
        }
]
```

OK, after reading the page source of Google search result page I think I know what the problem is:

Google loads search result with AJAX, so, when you change query words and search again, the page DOES　NOT refresh, that's why you can not get any DOM elements in the search results.

That means you have to add an event listener for DOMNodeInserted.

Code is like this:

```
function findH3(){
  $('h3.r').append('<b>a</b>')

}

searchResultArea.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', findH3);
```

Comment: Yeah, I did. And absolutely the problem now is that I can not get any DOM node of the page. And it seems that the script is run before the DOM is loaded though I add the run_at: document_end

Comment: @user2086454: Did you add permissions to the manifest, share the relevant code, it will be helpful further

Comment: Thanks. And I have figured out why myself. I use windows.onload to do that but I think your solution is a much better one. But here comes a new problem: now I can get the DOM element, I have alerted the text out. But I can not assign a style attribute to them. For example I write $('h3.r').css('background-color', 'red'), nothing happens.

Comment: I have solved the problem. It seems that you should first delete the extension and then reinstall it not just refresh it. I don't why, but it works.

Comment: reload is just not so beautifull ：）

Comment: @HankYang, where should I put this code `searchResultArea.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', findH3);
`?

Comment: `contentscript.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: searchResultArea is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

Add permissions of the URL(S) you target to the manifest file

```
{
 ---
    "permissions": [
        "https: //www.google.co.in/*"
    ]
 ---
}
```

## Reference

- [Permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html)