# Chrome extension not working on specific websites

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My chrome extension which looks for a phone number on a webpage is not working. Essentially, i expect an icon to appear besides the number. It works on other websites, but not on say google.com search results page. E.g.: https://www.google.com/#q=macy's%20redmond Do you know why?

Here is my code.

reverphonescript.js:

```
var hostname = document.location.hostname;
if (hostname.indexOf('xp')== -1)
{
     // Initiate recursion 
     wpReversePhoneLookup(document.body); 
     function wpReversePhoneLookup(elem) { // elem must be an element node
         var nodes = elem.childNodes
           , i = nodes.length
           , regexp = /([\(]|)\d*([\+)]|)\d*[-\.\(\ ][0-9][0-9][0-9][-\s\.\)]*(([0-9][0-9][0-9][-\s\.][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])|([ ][1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])|[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])]*/gi
           , node, phoneNode, a, result;
         while (node = nodes[--i]) {
             if (node.nodeType === 1) {
                 // Skip anchor tags, nested anchors make no sense
                 //if (node.nodeName.toUpperCase() !== 'A')
                    wpReversePhoneLookup(node);
             } else if (node.nodeType === 3) {
                 //   Please note that the regexp has NO global flag,
                 //    and that `node.textContent` shrinks when an address is found
                 while (result = regexp.exec(node.textContent)) { 
                     //console.log(result);
                     node = node.splitText(result.index); 
                     node = node.splitText(result[0].length); 
                     phoneNode = node.previousSibling
                     //console.log(phoneNode)
                      var link = "https://pro.lookup.whitepages.com/phones?number=" + result[0]; 
                      var imgURL = chrome.extension.getURL("images/rsz_wp_16.png");  
                      var img = new Image();
                      img.src = imgURL;
                      img.className = "wpChromeExtensionImg";
                      img.onclick = function() {
                        window.open( link ,"_blank" ,"width=1000, height=650");
                     };  
                     document.getElementsByClassName("wpChromeExtensionImg").src = imgURL; 
                     //Create link
                     wpLink = document.createElement('a');
                     wpLink.href = '#';   
                     //Append phoneNode
                     wpLink.appendChild(img)  
                     var refNode = phoneNode; 
                     refNode.parentNode.insertBefore(wpLink, refNode.nextSibling); 
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

And manifest.json:

```
{   // Required
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "name": "XP",
 "version": "1.0",
 "description": "XP Reverse Phone Lookup. ",
 "icons": { "128": "images/rsz_xp_128.png"
},

"web_accessible_resources": [
    "images/*.png", 
    "js/reversePhoneScript.js" 
  ],
  "browser_action": {
  "default_icon": {
    "19": "images/rsz_wp_19.png"
  },
  "default_title": "XP Reverse Phone Lookup"
},
  "permissions": [
  "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
],
 "content_scripts" : [
  {
    "matches" : ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "js" : ["js/reversePhoneScript.js"],
    "run_at" : "document_idle", //document_end
    "all_frames" : false
  }
]
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Kushal.

Comment: Possibly related/duplicate: [Use Chrome Extension to Modify Google Search Result Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149207/use-chrome-extension-to-modify-google-search-result-page)

Comment: No need to write "run_at" as "document_idle" as it is the default. Also rather than writing '"http://*/*", "https://*/*"', write "<all_urls>".

Comment: What does XP in line 2 do?

Answer (score 0):

use the chrome "inspect" tool to find your icon in the page. use the ctrl-f to find your icon in the page. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index

some css might be moving your icon to the far left of the screen, or much simply, no z-index tag is applied to your icon so it might be hiding behind something else. http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_pos_z-index.asp